# Force child span to use parent's font size in CSS when you can't control the child's CSS?

Tags: html, css

So I am watching a movie on a site and their subtitle reads like micro print. I wish to increase it. Only problem is, all their CSS is inline, for whatever reason. Each line of caption comes in its own inline style.

I have access to the parent span of the subtitles. I have tried to use !important to force the child to use the parent's style and the only thing that I have managed to change is the space between the lines. I guess this is because the child element comes with its own font size.

I am not a UI/UX developer. Is there any way to force a child span to use the font of the parent span?

The span I am trying to control:

```
<span id="stays-the-same" style="font-size:30pt !important"> //I tried introducing the font size here.
    <span style="white-space: pre-wrap; color: white; direction: ltr; opacity: 1; display: inline; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Liberation Sans, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; font-size: 10px; text-align: center; writing-mode: horizontal-tb;"><span style="background-color: transparent;">
        <span style="background-color: transparent;">
            New line of subs.
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

All the span inside "stays-the-same" change (re-created) when the sub-title changes.

Comment: HAve you tried to simply use the browser's zoom function?

Comment: @Johannes. Yeah. The text ends up half way in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the CSS styles you're trying to edit?

Comment: @RiverTam Updated the question to include CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to target the HTML elements directly. You may still need to use `!important` to override inline styling.

Add this using the Styles section of your browser's Inspect Element tool:

```
span#stays-the-same span {
(styling for first nested span here)
}

span#stays-the-same span span {
(styling for second nested span here)
}
```

Comment: It took me a bit to figure out where to enter this but it worked!  Thank you! I learned something new!

Comment: Ah, good call, sorry I didn't mention where to put it. I've edited my answer to add that for anyone looking for it in the future.